# Gradle Build Error Could not get unknown property supportVersion

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Error Message:

> Could not get unknown property 'supportVersion' for object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Build.gradle Codes:-

```
apply plugin:'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25

    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.eassycars.www.dlservices"

        minSdkVersion 16

        targetSdkVersion 25

        versionCode 1

        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

    }

}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

// google & support

 implementation "com.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler :$supportVersion"

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"

    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportVersion"

    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportVersion"

    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"

    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportVersion"

    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportVersion"

    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVersion"

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.0.4'
// utils

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'

    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'

    implementation 'com.github.Commit451:bypasses:1.0.4'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.0'

    implementation 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.9.1'

    implementation "com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1"

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
}
```

Can Anyone tell me that how to fix this error

Comment: what is `supportVersion` ? set `compileSdkVersion 27`

Answer (score 3):

you need to add above `android{}`  on your gradle

```
ext {
supportVersion='27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: It Say's                                                         Could not find method supportVersion() for arguments [27.0.3] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.

Comment: can you update your current gradle on this question?

Answer (score 2):

The error tells that there is no value for the variable $supportVersion. If you know exactly what version you would like to use then define `supportVersion` like you have defined `buildToolsVersion`. I am not sure but its the same for your case.

```
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
supportVersion '27.0.3'
```

Or replace `supportVersion` with `buildToolsVersion` in your existing file.

Comment: After supportVersion with buildToolsVersion I Found This Message Error Could not find method supportVersion() for arguments [27.0.3] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin must help you with finding the suitable supportVersion for your project.